Why I am getting TypeError: middleware is not a function
I am trying to learn redux on my own and following different tutorials around the internet. So, far I am doing good and able to understand many things by myself; however, I am stuck on the below code in which I am unable to understand what's going on:
const redux = require('redux')
const createStore = redux.createStore
const applyMiddleware = redux.applyMiddleware

const thunkMiddleware = require('redux-thunk').default
const axios = require('axios')

const initialState = {
    loading: false,
    users: [],
    error: ''
}

const FETCH_USERS_REQUEST = 'FETCH_USERS_REQUEST'
const FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS'
const FETCH_USERS_FAILURE = 'FETCH_USERS_FAILURE'

const fetchUsersRequest = () => {
    return {
        type: FETCH_USERS_REQUEST
    }
}

const fetchUsersSuccess = users => {
    return {
        type: FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS,
        payload: users
    }
}

const fetchUsersFailure = error => {
    return {
        type: FETCH_USERS_FAILURE,
        payload: error
    }
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_USERS_REQUEST:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            }

        case FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS:
            return {
                loading: false,
                users: action.payload,
                error: ''
            }

        case FETCH_USERS_FAILURE:
            return {
                loading: false,
                users: [],
                error: action.payload
            }
    }
}

const fetchUsers = () => {
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch(fetchUsersRequest())
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
            .then(response => {
                // response.data is the array of users
                const users = response.data.map(user => user.id)
                dispatch(fetchUsersSuccess(users))
            })
            .catch(error => {
                // error.message is the error description
                dispatch(fetchUsersFailure(error.message))
            })
    }
}

const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware))
store.subscribe(() => { console.log(store.getState()) })
store.dispatch(fetchUsers())

According to me, it should work but I am getting the below error, also need some help on how to debug the code:
TypeError: middleware is not a function
    at E:\Repos\Redux\Raw\node_modules\redux\dist\cjs\redux.cjs:407:51
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at E:\Repos\Redux\Raw\node_modules\redux\dist\cjs\redux.cjs:407:31
    at createStore (E:\Repos\Redux\Raw\node_modules\redux\dist\cjs\redux.cjs:133:33)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Repos\Redux\Raw\asyncActions.js:78:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1369:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1427:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1206:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)


According to the docs, that package does not have a default export. Use const { thunk } = require('redux-thunk') instead

You are following extremely outdated (half a decade!) tutorials - modern Redux does not look like this at all. The knowledge you will get from this tutorial will result in applications that have 2-5 times the amount of Redux code and are much more prone to bugs.
Please follow the official Redux tutorial instead to learn modern Redux with Redux Toolkit.
Also, do yourself the favor and start working with a better editor. VSCode is free and would tell you that createStore is deprecated.

Does this answer your question? react-mock-store: TypeError: middleware is not a function
